# jQuery: получение содержимого html-тэга включая родительский элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как проще всего с помощью `jQuery` получить содержимое html-тэга включая сам этот тэг? Для примера: как, используя селектор `$("#test")`, записать в значение переменной следующую разметку целиком?

```
<div id="test">
    <p> тест </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript

Вариант 1

```js
var result = document.getElementById('test').outerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p> тест </p>
</div>
```

Вариант 2

```js
var result = document.querySelector('#test').outerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p> тест </p>
</div>
```

JQuery

```js
var result = $('#test')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p> тест </p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Как обычно, через `jQuery` элегантнее всего :)